# Prediction of Binary Tuples

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

Which statistical model could useful for the following case?

**Framework:** an chat-and-call application like Whatsapp where users can use 3 features:

- chat with a contact
- send a message in a chat-group
- make a call

Let us assign to every user a tuple of length three $(X_{chat},X_{call},X_{groups})$,
where $$X_i=\begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if feature i was used}\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}  $$

For example, Tom is assigned Tuple $(1,1,0)$ which means he used regular chat and calls but did not used group-chats.

I am looking for a model that can output the most likely tuple, and / or could assign a probability to each element in the tuple.

For example $(0.99,0.5,0.1)$ would mean that the user has 99% chances of using regular chat, 50% chances of making a call and only 10% of sending a message in a group. note that the feature usage is not exclusive, meaning that a user can use regular chat and calls on the same day / week, hence the probabilities do not necessarily sum up to 100%.

**As independent variables**, I have user-specific volumes per feature over the past week, for example: Tom sent 61 messages through regular chats and had 2 calls and sent 25 messages in groups.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like vanilla binary classification, except that you train multiple binary classifiers on the same data to predict different targets. If it needs to be score-based, then logistic regression is an excellent option. Would that work?

Comment: It looks like multivariate probit could be a good place to start.